# "To all of you wanting to improve your English"

Tags: sentence-construction

So I have the sentence "To all of you wanting to improve your English ..." Is that sentence correct? Shouldn't it be something like "All those who want to improve their English"?

Comment: Both sentences are grammatical, the first indicates there is more to follow, the second is incomplete. The question lacks what you are trying to say. For example, "All those who want to improve their English should attend the new class after school."

Answer (score 1):

As with any other language, in English there's usually more than one way to express a certain thought.

*"To all (of you) who ..."* is grammatical, but it is not a complete sentence.  It is (I believe) an adverbial phrase that specifies the intended audience of the main part of the sentence (which is usually some kind of advice).  For example:

> **To all of you who want to become better writers**, the most important thing you can do is *write*.  Period.

*"All those who ..."* says the same thing in a different way.  It is a noun phrase that is the subject of a sentence (which can also take the form of advice):

> **All of you who want to become better writers** should *write*.  Period.