# Wise men are the people

Tags: phrase-usage

Is the structure "wise men are the people having or showing the ability" natural in Engish? Should it be "Wise men are the people who have or show the ability"?

> Wise men are the people having or showing the ability to make good judgments based on a deep understanding and experience of life.

Comment: See also [*“To all of you **wanting** to improve your English”*](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/214883/to-all-of-you-wanting-to-improve-your-english/214884) (contrasted with *...all of you **who want** to improve...*). Idiomatically, the ***who*** versions are usually more "natural".

Comment: @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica to me *"Wise men are the people who have"* is just a different way to put *"Wise men are the people having"*... Can we assume that the latter is a reduced form of something else? Then what would be the full form? *"Wise men are the people **who are** having"*?

Comment: Yes, it does. Thank you.

Comment: @AndrewTobilko: Definitely not! *[Category X] are the people who are having [Attribute Y]* looks like some weird kind of "Indian English" usage! There's no reason to suppose *either* of OP's alternatives are somehow "reduced forms" of some longer phrasing, either. They're both just ***alternative phrasings*** (where it so happens that the ***who*** version is more natural for OP's *exact* context).

Comment: @NewPlanet: Note that your example is a "copula" construction - where the verb ***to be*** appears (as ***are***) in between two noun phrases that are being ***equated***. Usually it's perfectly okay to reverse the positions of those two noun phrases - in your case giving us *People who have or show this ability are wise men* (almost exactly equivalent to *Wise men are people who have or show this ability*). Also note that idiomatically we wouldn't usually include the definite article ***the*** before ***people*** here.